# How do I separate bulk data in my Google Analytics automated dashboard into month by month data

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-sheets

Hi I've been working on a google analytics dashboard but having a hard time separating data by different months. The script I have pulls the bulk date from the start to end date and I would like to separate it month by month. Below is the script . Thanks in advance!

```
function runDemo() {
  try {

    var firstProfile = getFirstProfile();
    var results = getReportDataForProfile(firstProfile);
    outputToSpreadsheet(results);

  } catch(error) {
    Browser.msgBox(error.message);
  }
}
function getFirstProfile() {
  var accounts = Analytics.Management.Accounts.list();
  if (accounts.getItems()) {
    var firstAccountId = accounts.getItems()[0].getId();

    var webProperties = Analytics.Management.Webproperties.list(firstAccountId);
    if (webProperties.getItems()) {

      var firstWebPropertyId = webProperties.getItems()[0].getId();
      var profiles = Analytics.Management.Profiles.list(firstAccountId, firstWebPropertyId);

      if (profiles.getItems()) {
        var firstProfile = profiles.getItems()[0];
        return firstProfile;

      } else {
        throw new Error('No views (profiles) found.');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('No webproperties found.');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('No accounts found.');
  }
}
function getReportDataForProfile(firstProfile) {

  var profileId = firstProfile.getId();
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;
  var startDate = getLastNdays(14);   // 2 weeks (a fortnight) ago.
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);      // Today.

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:keyword',              // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    'sort': '-ga:sessions,ga:keyword',       // Sort by sessions descending, then keyword.
    'segment': 'dynamic::ga:isMobile==Yes',  // Process only mobile traffic.
    'filters': 'ga:source==google',          // Display only google traffic.
    'start-index': '1',
    'max-results': '250'                     // Display the first 250 results.
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
      tableId,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
      optArgs);

  if (results.getRows()) {
    return results;

  } else {
    throw new Error('No views (profiles) found');
  }
}

function getLastNdays(nDaysAgo) {
  var today = new Date();
  var before = new Date();
  before.setDate(today.getDate() - nDaysAgo);
  return Utilities.formatDate(before, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
function outputToSpreadsheet(results) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();

  // Print the headers.
  var headerNames = [];
  for (var i = 0, header; header = results.getColumnHeaders()[i]; ++i) {
    headerNames.push(header.getName());
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, headerNames.length)
      .setValues([headerNames]);

  // Print the rows of data.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.getRows().length, headerNames.length)
      .setValues(results.getRows());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to add `ga:month`, `ga:yearMonth`, or `ga:nthMonth` to your list of dimensions and process the resulting data. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time for available time granularity dimensions.